# opencv tarda mucho en acceder a la camara usb

Tags: python, opencv

Tengo un programa de python que mediante opencv accede a la camara web, realicé pruebas y funciona de acuerdo a lo deseado, sin embargo eso era al usar una camara web generica por usb, pero al conectar la camara que se solicita usar (Logi C270 HD Webcam) el frame que muestra el video obtenido tarda mucho tiempo en mostrarse, al rededor de 5 minutos en comparacion de los segundos que tardaba con la webcam generica, probé a usar la misma camara pero de un colega y el problema persiste

```
import cv2 

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

if not cap.isOpened():
  print("No se puede abrir la cámara")
  exit()

while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if not ret:
        print("No se puede recibir el fotograma (¿final de la transmisión?). Saliendo ...")
        break
    # Mostrar imagen
    cv2.imshow('Camara USB', frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
        break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: No creo que funcione pero podrías probar estableciendo la resolución y velocidad de los fotogramas añadiendo lo siguiente a tu código:
    cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH,  "Ancho") 
    cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, "Alto") 
    cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS, "FPS")